# boost::shared_ptr<Type> does not serialize the data and gives error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, serialization, boost

Again I have issue while serializing shared pointer using boost and below is code :

//Content.hpp file

```
#include <boost/serialization/string.hpp>
#include <boost\serialization\shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/list.hpp>


struct Content
    {

        std::string type;
    boost::shared_ptr<Content> mycontent;  // mycontent is of type Content


    private:
        friend class boost::serialization::access;
        template<class Archive>
        void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version)
        {
            ar & id;
            ar & name;
        ar & mycontent;
        }   

    public:
        Content(void);
        Content(const parameter_strings & parms);

        ~Content(void);
    };
```

// Content.cpp file

```
Content::Content(void)
{
}

Content::~Content(void)
{
}

Content::Content(const parameter_strings & parms)
{
   // implementation part
}
```

if I comment line " -- boost::shared_ptr mycontent; --" it compiles without error but i need to use shared_ptr and hence it gives error :

**it gives error : error C4308: negative integral constant converted to unsigned type**

I have included all required header files also but still issue exists.

Comment: possible duplicate of [boost serialization fails - gives compile time error C4308](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22409755/boost-serialization-fails-gives-compile-time-error-c4308)

Answer (score 1):

I already answered this [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22409755/boost-serialization-fails-gives-compile-time-error-c4308#comment34359346_22415233) here:

> @user3382670 making the destructor virtual enabled RTTI for your class. This means that typeid(variable) will return the proper runtime type (most derived class) insetad of the statically known type with pointers and references. –  sehe Mar 22 at 1:01

Also, since you don't require polymorphism there should be no such problem in the first place: see it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/685278cd2695f50b)**

```
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/string.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/shared_ptr.hpp>

struct Content
{
    std::string id, name;
    boost::shared_ptr<Content> mycontent;

  private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<class Archive>
        void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int /*version*/)
        {
            ar & id;
            ar & name;
            ar & mycontent;
        }   

  public:
    Content() {}
    typedef int parameter_strings;
    Content(const parameter_strings & parms) { }

    ~Content() {}
};

int main()
{
    boost::archive::text_oarchive ao(std::cout);

    Content x;
    ao << x;
}
```

Comment: i tried the above code.. but still same issue exists..  should i make my destructor non-virtual ??